# javascript list to HTML list

Tags: javascript, html, list

I'm sure this is a simple one, and I'm close, but can't get exactly what I want.

The end result I need to create (in HTML) is like this:

```
<li id="EventList">
<ul class="calendar-menu">
    <li>
        <time class="anthracite"><b>24</b> Feb</time>
        <small class="green">10:30</small>
        Event's description
    </li>
    <br />
    <li>
        <time class="anthracite"><b>24</b> Feb</time>
        <small class="green">10:30</small>
        Event's description
    </li>
    <br />
    <li>
        <time class="anthracite"><b>24</b> Feb</time>
        <small class="green">10:30</small>
        Event's description
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to fill in the date, time and description elements dynamically, based on data that I get from an ajax call to the database.

Here's what I have been trying to get to create the HTML list. Eventually the data will come from

```
function GetList() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ExampleList.aspx/GetList",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                var datos = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);

                $("#EventList").html('');
                var list = '<ul>'
                $.each(datos, function (i, v) {

                Something in here to populate the <li> tags? 

                }); 
                list += '</ul>'

                $("#EventList").append(list);
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText).Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction with some example code?

Comment: well we can't tell you exactly because we don't know the structure of your `datos` object but basically you can create some HTML string by joining bits of hard-coded HTML strings to your object's properties. e.g. `list += <li><time class="anthracite"><b>' + v.whateverYourHoursFieldIsCalled + '</b>'`...etc

Comment: In theory it could work if you wrap that `append(thing)` in a `$`, i.e. `$("#EventList").append($(list));`

Comment: @Brian append() can accept a plain old string so wrapping it in a jQuery object first seems like a bit overkill. I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Can it now? Cool, good to know.

Comment: @Brian http://api.jquery.com/append/ - I'm not a clairvoyant, it's just in the documentation :-). In fact it accepts a number of different things, as you can see.

Comment: `<br />` tags between your list items in invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try:

```
list+= '<li><time class="anthracite"><b>'+v.number+'</b> '+v.month+'</time><small class="green">'+v.time+'</small>'+v.eventName+'</li>';
```

You can continue writing `list` to complete the `li's` with the fetched data.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Roy, that was exactly what I needed